# How can get value of a Range by COM Excel in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel

I using COM Excel in PHP.
I want convert code to get value of a Range from vba to php:

```
values=oSheet.Range(oSheet.Cells(1, 1), oSheet.Cells(2, 2)).Value
```

I had try this code but result output a empty array :

```
$excel = new \COM("Excel.Application")  or die("Unable to instanciate excel");
    //bring it to front
    $excel->Visible = 1;
   //dont want alerts ... run silent
    $excel->DisplayAlerts = 0;
    $wkb = $excel->Workbooks->open("E:\\Test.xls");
    $sheet=$wkb->Worksheets("Log");
    $range = $sheet->Range("A1:B2");
    $values = $range->Value;    
    var_dump( (array)$values);
```

How can get value of a Range by COM Excel in PHP?